# How to make a list.sort() key for strings containing decimals and scientific notation?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to get the paths to files which are in folders named by time stamps in seconds. 
Folder name examples `0.000989965428461` and `1.00189731936e-05`
And I do need to write out the time as well.

I tried some variations for the `key=` in `list.sort(key='')` getting different outcomes from bad to really bad.
I lack understanding of the underlying problem: `list.sort()` "understands" that my strings are numbers, but does not understand that x.xxe-xx is a number format, too.

What I have to get my pathfiles and the time written out as csv

```py
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
import os
import csv
import re

param='mitteQuer0'

fieldOne= 'U_zCut.vtk'
fieldTwo= 'p_rgh_zCut.vtk'
fieldThree= 'alpha.water_zCut.vtk'

fieldOneVTKs= []
fieldTwoVTKs=[]
fieldThreeVTKs=[]
time=[]
steps=[]
timeNsteps=[]

#Get path of the script
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
#Make folder path
path = dir_path + '/postProcessing/'+param

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    dirs.sort()
    for name in dirs:
        fieldOneVTKs.append(os.path.join(path, name+'/'+fieldOne))
        fieldTwoVTKs.append(os.path.join(path, name+'/'+fieldTwo))
        fieldThreeVTKs.append(os.path.join(path, name+'/'+fieldThree))

with open('time.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write('Zeit,')
    csvfile.write('\n')
    for item in dirs:
        csvfile.write(item +',')
        csvfile.write('\n')
```

Lot's of working code after that to use the paths with paraview.

I use `os.walk` and `list.sort()`, but the sorting does not work the way I need it to.
What I get when looking just at the folder names:

```py
0.000970221197898
0.000980099262637
0.000989965428461
1.00189731936e-05
2.00244250065e-05
3.00104958923e-05
```

What I need:

```py
1.00189731936e-05
2.00244250065e-05
3.00104958923e-05
0.000970221197898
0.000980099262637
0.000989965428461
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `float` value of the string as key to sort, by replacing `dirs.sort()` with `dirs.sort(key=float)`

For example

```
>>> lst = ['0.000970221197898', '0.000980099262637', '0.000989965428461', '1.00189731936e-05', '2.00244250065e-05', '3.00104958923e-05']
>>> lst.sort(key=float)
>>> 
>>> pprint (lst)
['1.00189731936e-05',
 '2.00244250065e-05',
 '3.00104958923e-05',
 '0.000970221197898',
 '0.000980099262637',
 '0.000989965428461']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed.